# Upload data in one tab and see the result in next tab

Tags: php

I have a webpage with 2 tabs, one is for uploading data and second is for showing the result. The first tab is a form which is redirected to a php file (upload.php) on submit. 
I want to upload data in first tab using php and then without redirecting to another page,go to the next tabb and see the result there. 
Can anyone tell me if this is possible to run a php file on the background? I'm so new in php programming and didn't find anything helpful searching my question.

Comment: You can use AJAX on your current page to submit your form, the upload.php file can do its stuff and return the results back to your current page. Once you have the results then you can update the 2nd tab.

Comment: Yes, it is. But there is nearly no way to help you further without knowing more details, and seeing what you've tried so far to get it work